# Password access not working with AWS Cloudfront website using Drupal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Drupal website that's been configured with AWS Cloudfront.

My problem is that now passworded access to the CMS is not happening. The page asks for the username/password and then I click on the "Login" button and it gives me "access denied" message.

The password is fine so I'm sure this is a Cloudfront problem. Can anyone please assist me why this is happening?

Comment: Can you provide your distribution setting?

Comment: Hi which settings you require from distribution settings?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the dashboard how you have set up the Cloud Front distribution

Comment: One thing I noticed the cookies are not being saved when i open the site .. i shall post screenshots shortly

Comment: Ugh I'm having a tough time figuring out how to upload images into this page. Please assist. Thanks!

Comment: Use this http://imgur.com/?third_party=1 upload the image there and post the link in comment

Comment: Ok http://imgur.com/R00ButD
http://imgur.com/NpPPDUt

Comment: Ok white list Origin, Host, Referrer, Authorization Headers

Comment: For all behaviors?

Comment: Yes for all behaviors

Comment: Ok done I'm waiting for deployment

Comment: Hi what's the behavior setting "Forward Cookies" ?

Comment: For web distributions, you can choose whether you want CloudFront to forward cookies to your origin and to cache separate versions of your objects based on cookie values in viewer requests. And if the above setting change does not work you will have to forward all cookies.

Comment: Yeah the login to cms form still doesn't log me in after whitelisting all you said. Should i set the forward cookies option?

Comment: Yes please set that

Comment: Yes the "forward cookies" option seems to have worked.. but I'll check all functionalites of the cms before setting this question as answered.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am experiencing the same issue after moving a Drupal 8 site to AWS. I am not using Cloudfront.

Answer (score 5):

The issue happening is with Authentication headers and Cookies not being forwarded to the parent server from the Cloud Front Distribution. Whitelisting Origin, Host, Referrer, Authorization Headers and Forwarding all cookies will fix this issue.

Comment: could you elaborate? I am using a basic EC2 instance and seem to be having the same problem. Does your suggestion still apply?

Answer (score 0):

"The `forward cookies` setting in the Cloud Front worked for me."

I have not verified other functionality of the website but seems like it will work. It seems like the CloudFront will be useless since it will sending every request to the origin.

`AWS CloudFront -> Distributions -> (Your Distributioon) -> Edit behavior`

[image]