# AWS EC2 Instance Drupal 8 Site Access Denied

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, drupal, amazon-ec2, drupal-7

I have just migrated a Drupal 8 site to AWS EC2 instance. Everything seems to be working except for one thing - when I log in, I get Access Denied message.

It appears that the website validates the user admin credentials and redirects to the correct page at user/1 but the authentication cookie/session are not handled properly.

I have found this ticket but am not sure how much it pertains to my situation since I am not using (as far as I know) the Cloudfront.

[Password access not working with AWS Cloudfront website using Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595022/password-access-not-working-with-aws-cloudfront-website-using-drupal)

Any help or advice on this is appreciated.

Comment: Please describe your infrastructure configuration in more detail. Are you using a CDN like CloudFront? Are you using more than one EC2 instance with a load balancer?

Comment: No. Just a basic EC2 instance. No Cloudfront or load balancer yet.

Comment: I think you are using different passwords and have sticky sessions enabled on your ELB. Please disable sticky session and try again. If works, then use Application sessions instead of ELB sessions.

Comment: @Sam what is ELB?

Comment: @Sam if you mean Elastic Load Balancer, I have mentioned that I am not using a load balancer, just a basic EC2 instance.